# schrodinger 2nd order

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

Okay I am having trouble with the question, and before I start, I have not done any working as it how the questions worded and asking for is confusing me, so I will try and convey what I think it telling me, but I just cannot see how the solution given is being formed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghA2P.png)

It is part b) I am stuf with as I dont quite understand the statement

"By assuming $B(x)$ gives the behaviour of $\psi(x)$ for $0\leq x <<1$"

at first I was think maybe a binomial expansion but could not see a way of applying that to either the differential or the wave function but I only have one solution for that, that I know of.

I then thought maybe that as x<<1 then as there is a $x^2$ in the denominator then all the other would be invalid this give an second order of

$$y''-\frac{\left(k^2-1\right)}{4x^2}y=0$$ and I am not quite sure how to solve that.

And that all I have come up with so far, I really am not sure how this condition is being applied, to be honest it my first time tackling this kinda of problem, so a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Sorry I should point out it part b) of this problem that is the issue.

also I have just notice how can x=0 and also be x<<1

Comment: $0\le x \ll 1$ means something like $0\le x\le 10^{-5}$ for example

Comment: Ok I understand that, but I still cant see how to solve this differential, I did think change of variables but that wont work as I am not sure what variable to use. If what you say is ture then surley my assuption that we would only be with K^2-1/x^2 is correct as the x^2 would be th largest out of the 1/x and the 1/4. But then I am left with a 2nd order that I am not sure how to solve.

Comment: I just tried a cuchy euler and I dont think that correct beacuse I make the solution $Ax^{\sqrt{2-k^2}}$